# Precise syntax of CSS3 colors

Tags: css, syntax, colors

I couldn't find a precise definition of legal syntax for CSS3 colors, either as regular expression, BNF or whatever strict formal definition there might be.  Some info can be derived from the verbal description in the [CSS3 Color Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-color-20030514/) (for example that comma separated lists may contain whitespace), but I don't see whether e.g. leading zeros in something like

```
rgb(010,005,255)
rgba(050%,1%,01%,0)
```

are actually legal, or omitting leading zeros of decimal fractions, like

```
rgba(100,100,100,.5)
```

I'm not talking about what is tolerated by browsers, I'm asking whether this is officially legal CSS3 syntax as I'm interested in the use of these color definitions in non-browser applications as well.

Comment: Is http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/ what you look for?

Comment: along with http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#numbers

Comment: @Matijs: This document defines the syntax more or less by example, doesn't it?  There are several aspects that don't become 100% clear to me.  In addition to the above mentioned ones e.g. whether percentage or hue values may have a fractional part, whether values may be preceded by a "+".  A strict and comprehensive definition by regular expressions, BNF or else wouldn't leave this kind of uncertainty.

Comment: @david: Thanks for the hint, I think I need to have a closer look at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#tokenization

Comment: @ThomasW it's the spec… related to your question about hues having a fractional part I found http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Jan/0016.html

Comment: @Matijs: Thanks for digging that. That confirms the conclusion I came to by looking at the CSS Syntax and Data Types spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found already, the [CSS3 Color Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-color-20030514/) specification says

*The format of an RGB value in the functional notation is 'rgb(' followed by a comma-separated list of three numerical values (either three integer values or three percentage values) followed by ')'*

But you then need to look in [basic data types section of CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#numbers) to find out what an integer or a percentage value is and it says...

*Some value types may have integer values (denoted by ) or real number values (denoted by ). Real numbers and integers are specified in decimal notation only. An  consists of one or more digits "0" to "9". A  can either be an , or it can be zero or more digits followed by a dot (.) followed by one or more digits. Both integers and real numbers may be preceded by a "-" or "+" to indicate the sign. -0 is equivalent to 0 and is not a negative number.*

So integers and numbers can have leading zeros.

Then later on basic data types says

*The format of a percentage value (denoted by  in this specification) is a  immediately followed by '%'.*

So percentages can have leading zeros too.